# Angular2 .reset() not resetting @Input values in firefox

Tags: angular, typescript

Okay all, having browser issues and not sure if I'm leaving something out. Here's my plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/sStsEL/ My problem is when I edit a line item and click Revert during the edit, Chrome sets my values back to the data model values, but Firefox wipes all fields. What am I missing? Maybe I should escalate this to the devs, but is there a workaround for this? If I console.log the @Input value in the NgOnChanges function, I get correct data. Everything can be seen logged on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at `FormGroupDirective`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[formGroup]',
  providers: [formDirectiveProvider],
  host: {'(submit)': 'onSubmit($event)', '(reset)': 'onReset()'}, <== reset event
  exportAs: 'ngForm'
})
export class FormGroupDirective extends ControlContainer implements Form,
    OnChanges {   
  ...
  onReset(): void { this.resetForm(); }

  resetForm(value: any = undefined): void {
    this.form.reset(value);
    this._submitted = false;
  }
```

where you can notice `reset` event on `[formGroup]` and its handler is running `form.reset`

As your button element has `type="reset"` and you have `click` event on this element and also bind `disabled` property

```
<button [disabled]="fg.pristine" type="reset" (click)="revert()"
```

the behavior in Chrome and Firefox will be different:

https://jsfiddle.net/f1t5khwk/

As you can see in example above after clicking on button you're setting `disabled` property to `true` so after that `reset` event in Chrome doesn't bubble while Firefox continues to catch the `reset` event.

So your workaround is replacing

```
type="reset"
```

with

```
type="button"
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DIU5Bv?p=preview)**